# Add menu item on frontend after install module

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

In custom module I'm create web page for frontend (contact form).

Is it possible and where, after install module automatically add link in frontend menu eg. Contact (http://localhost:8069/contact/form).

Now I menu item add manualy.

Answer (score 0):

try to add an xml file with the code below:

```
    <record id="contact_menu_id" model="website.menu">
        <field name="name">Contact</field>
        <field name="url">/contact/form</field>
        <field name="parent_id" ref="website.main_menu" />
        <field name="sequence" type="int">5</field>
    </record>
```